# Getting Resource as InputStream in Playframework

Tags: java, playframework, inputstream

I have the following Problem in my Play-Application: 
I placed a file called "logfileSearch.properties" in my conf folder. Then i wanted to get a inputStream with mentioned file in it.

```
@Inject
Provider<Application> app;

public CustomNodeList newSearch() throws IOException {
    Application application = app.get();
    ClassLoader classLoader = application.classloader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("logfileSearch.properties");
    .....
}
```

With this Code i got a NullPointerException in the line:

```
Application application = app.get();
```

If someone here is able to help me i would be very happy.

More Info:

- Play version: 2.5.14
- Scala version: 2.11.11

Comment: Is this method `newSearch` in your controller? Where are you receiving `app` injection? Where is your constructor?

Answer (score 1):

you can use current class loader as described in [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Include-semantics:-locating-resources)
like:

```
   this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("logfileSearch.properties");
```

Comment: The return value of this method is null in my case. But thank you for helping.